# How do I create a counter to count the number of people who had the maximum salary entered?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab4a{
  public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  int numemployees, max, freq;

  System.out.print("Enter number of employees: ");
  numemployees = keyboard.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Enter salary for " + numemployees + " employees:");
  int[] salaries = new int [numemployees];

  max = salaries[0];
  for (int i=0; i < salaries.length; i++){
    salaries[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (salaries[i] > max)
      max = salaries[i];
  }

  System.out.println("Maximum salary is " + max);
  System.out.println(" employees received " + max);
}
```

So the output for this would be

Enter number of employees: 3
Enter salary for 3 employees:
10000
15000
15000
Maximum salary is 15000
  employees received 15000

I WANT IT TO SAY, "2 employees received 15000".  That's all I need for it to do. Please help me how to establish that counter using another loop... as simple as possible! Thanks!

Comment: please show some compassion for the people you're asking to help you. Format your code, don't use all caps, all that jazz.

Comment: If you know the max salary, can't you look through your array of salaries and count how many salaries were equal to that max?

Comment: Firstly, write a loop which get salary of all employee, then do get max from them.

Comment: Why the suggestions to loop a second time?  Not necessary or desirable.

Comment: yeah, not needed second loop. as he storing values in array.That I did't see.

Answer (score 2):

Amend your loop like this:

```
max = salaries[0];
freq = 1;
for (int i=0; i < salaries.length; i++){
  salaries[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
  if (salaries[i] > max) {
    freq = 1;
    max = salaries[i];
  } else if (salaries[i] == max) {
    ++freq;
  }
}
System.out.println(freq + " employees received " + max);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = 0;

for (int i=0; i < salaries.length; i++){

     if (salaries[i] == max)

     count++;

}

System.out.println(count+" employees received "+max);
```

Comment: The orginal code had all the bits needed, no need to add a second loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
int count =0;
System.out.println("Maximum salary is " + max);

System.out.println(" employees received " + max);

for(int i=0;i< salaries.length ;i++)
{
    if(salaries[i] == max)
        count++;
}
if(count>1)
{
    System.out.println(count+" employees received " + max);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go -

package com.walmart.services;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab4a {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int numemployees, max, freq = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter number of employees: ");

    numemployees = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter salary for " + numemployees + " employees:");

    int[] salaries = new int[numemployees];

    max = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < salaries.length; i++) {

        salaries[i] = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (salaries[i] > max) {
            freq = 1;
            max = salaries[i];
        } else if (salaries[i] == max) {
            freq++;
        }


    }
    System.out.println("Maximum salary is " + max);

    System.out.println(" employees received " + freq);
}
```

}